# VBA Runtime Error 9 - Subscript out of range

Tags: vba, excel, userform, subscript

I am attempting to create a user form that will propagate the first available row of the excel sheet with information. I am struggling to get the range correct, and the form is currently showing 'Subscript out of range' ; 'Runtime error 9'. There also seems to be a problem with the 'if' statement, but following the standard advice online doesn't seem to have helped solve the problem.

If anyone has any idea where I'm going wrong (I'm very new to this) that would be great.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()  
BusinessAreaBox.List = Array("option one", "option two")  
End Sub  

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()  
Dim RowCount As Long  
RowCount = Sheets("Sheet1").Range.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, "A")  
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")  
.Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = BusinessArea1.Value  
.Offset(RowCount, 1).Value = BusinessContact1.Value  
.Offset(RowCount, 2).Value = LPSContact1.Value  
.Offset(RowCount, 4).Value = ProjectedFTE1.Value  
.Offset(RowCount, 5).Value = DateOfMostRecentMeeting1.Value  
.Offset(RowCount, 6).Value = FTEComment1.Value  
.Offset(RowCount, 7).Value = ProposedMove1.Value  
.Offset(RowCount, 8).Value = DeskUtilisation1.Value  
.Offset(RowCount, 9).Value = OtherComment1.Value  
.Offset(RowCount, 10).Value = Actions1.Value  
If RegularMeeting1.Value = True Then  
.Offset(RowCount, 3).Value = "Yes"  
Else  
.Offset(RowCount, 3).Value = "No"  
End If  
RegularMeeting1.Value = True Or False  
End With  
End Sub  

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()  
  Unload Me  
End Sub
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with this line : `RowCount = Sheets("Sheet1").Range.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, "A")`? I'm guessing that this is the one that is in yellow?

Comment: That is the source of the error. I'm trying to get it to populate the first set of information onto "sheet 1", row 2, and from that point onwards to the first available line. I must admit that I took that line from an example online but I can't see what the line should read - any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: [Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/8917/vba-run-time-errors/27748/run-time-error-9-subscript-out-of-range#t=201701311609360342424)

Comment: Wait a sec, you're trying to *write* to `Sheet1!A2`? Then why are you *reading* from it (in a nonsensical contorted can't-possibly-work-way)? If you want to *write* to a cell, then the cell's value needs to be on the *left-hand-side* of the assignment; it's no different than reading/writing from/to a variable, really.

Comment: @Mat'sMug; if `RowCount = 0` then she's writing to `Sheet1!A2` at `.Offset(RowCount, 0).Value` if `RowCount <> 0` she's not.

Comment: @simpLEMAn yeah, well, *one* problem is that `RowCount` isn't being assigned with a legal statement in the first place.

Comment: @Mat'sMug; Oh, didn't see the `Sheets("Sheet1").Range.Sheets("Sheet1")`.  This should be better - `RowCount = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, "A").Value2`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may be after this

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(, 11).Value = Array(BusinessArea1.Value, _
                                                                              BusinessContact1.Value, _
                                                                              LPSContact1.Value, _
                                                                              IIf(RegularMeeting1.Value, "Yes", "No"), _
                                                                              ProjectedFTE1.Value, _
                                                                              DateOfMostRecentMeeting1.Value, _
                                                                              FTEComment1.Value, _
                                                                              ProposedMove1.Value, _
                                                                              DeskUtilisation1.Value, _
                                                                              OtherComment1.Value, _
                                                                              Actions1.Value)

    End With
    RegularMeeting1.Value = True Or False '<--| what is this supposed to do?
End Sub
```

Comment: @JohnMuggins, thanks. But let's wait for JessicaLucy's feedback

Comment: Unfortunately no luck with this. As before the range brought up an issue. I'll see if there's an issue elsewhere that could be causing a problem but many thanks for the help regardless!

Comment: what line is raising the issue and what's the error description?

Answer (score 0):

Try writing to the cells this way.  You need to active the sheet and cell first.

```
Dim myArr As Variant

myArr = Array(BusinessArea1.Value, _
              LPSContact1.Value, _
              ProjectedFTE1.Value, _
              DateOfMostRecentMeeting1.Value, _
              FTEComment1.Value, _
              ProposedMove1.Value, _
              DeskUtilisation1.Value, _
              OtherComment1.Value, _
              Actions1.Value)

sheet1.activate
sheet1.range("A2").activate
for I = 0 to ubound(myArr)
    activecell.value = myArr(I)
    activecell.Offset(1,0).activate
Next I
```

Comment: It would be nice to see SO answers that stop spreading the idea that using `.Activate` and relying on `ActiveCell` (and `Selection`) when you don't *have to* is anywhere near a good idea.

Comment: I second Mat's Mug on that - see **[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/2687063)**